# django template renders "&lt;bound method.." instead of context variables

Tags: python, django, templates, html-safe

I've got a template '`cart_summary.html`' which renders fine when I it appears as an include on another template `{% include 'cart/cart_summary.html' %}`.

However when I render it directly from a view function (called by ajax), my context variables do not render as expected:

```
# views.py
def add_to_cart(request):
    ...
    cart = request.session['cart']
    ...
    return render_to_response('cart/cart_summary.html', {'cart': cart})
```

my cart_summary.html template -

```
<a src="{% url cart-page pk=cart.pk %}">
    <span> CART ({{ cart.count }}) &pound;{{ cart.get_total }} </span>
    <img id="cart_icon" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/cart_icon.tiff">
</a>
```

And this is kind of stuff I'm getting returned to the browser -

```
<span> CART (&lt;bound method ManyRelatedManager.count of &lt;django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x106bfa150&gt;&gt;) &pound; </span>
<img id="cart_icon" src="images/cart_icon.tiff">
```

What do I need to do to get the properly rendered string?

Comment: Use render instead of render_to_response to fix {{ STATIC_URL }}.

Comment: Replacing the render_to_response() call with render() results in a server 500 error.

Comment: Cause you didn't do it right. What happens if you `print 'count :', cart.count()` in the view ?

Comment: Thanks @jpic, that's it, I was returning the a method rather than methods return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is returning a method instead of a value.

Probably it is returning `queryset.count` instead of `queryset.count()`

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of debugging some spectacularly poor code (my code), I found the error. It was actually in the Cart model. The count function was written so that it was returning a method rather than the output of a method

```
def count(self):
    return self.items.count
```

should have been

```
def count(self):
    self.items.count()
```

I was thrown off the scent by the fact it was being converted to html safe code, (that and all the other errors in my code).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
from django import template
return render_to_response('cart/cart_summary.html', {'cart': cart}, context_instance = template.RequestContent(request))
```

Comment: Thanks Raunak. Adding the context instance doesn't change the output. It's still not processing my context variables.